# Extracting select functions / paring down jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a service or simple way of paring down jQuery to a more manageable size, sort of like how you can roll your own jQuery UI? I loathe the idea of loading an entire library for a set of 2-3 functions, so if anyone has come across a relatively easy way of accomplishing this goal, please share your wisdom.

And no, I don't consider [vanilla.js](http://vanilla-js.com/) a solution. ;-)

Comment: Keep in mind that you may not actually want to do this. If you use a major CDN or load jQuery via Google.com, then many users will already have it cached. A trimmed-down version would actually be worse for user experience in that case than the whole enchilada.

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't considered that using it via Google might actually be faster than hosting it locally due to cache. Do you have any statistics on this to back it up? I'd assume not, but I gotta ask.

Comment: Hahaha! I didn't know about this vanilla.js site, but I love it! :D It was fun to read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Zepto, which is a completely different library with less size and functionality, but is made compatible with jQuery.

http://zeptojs.com/

They say about themselves:

> Zepto is a minimalist JavaScript library for modern browsers with a
>   largely jQuery-compatible API. If you use jQuery, you already know how
>   to use Zepto.